# Time Delay between ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to call service which returns one row of information at a time. I will fetch 100 such rows. I want a particular time gap between each hit to the service. It does not have to be exact, but at least 200 ms. I had been using jquery for the calls. Something like:

```
 for 1 to 100
    window.setTimeout(function(rowNumber){
    $.ajax({
    url: 
    datatype: 'json'
    async:false
    success: function to display row
    });
    }, 10000, someParam);
```

Also, I have this call inside a `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` function.
What happens is that I get a 10 second delay in the beginning, but then all the rows appear in an avalanche. I need a delay between each call.

Thanks!

Comment: sorry for the formatting! I couldn't get the code formatting to work. Maybe I am missing something

Comment: Don't know a whole lot about Ajax, but your post should be formatted now if you accept the edit. For future reference you can highlight your code and use the `{}` button, or indent your code 4 spaces.

Comment: forget this... I think your question has been answered

Comment: Yes. I have used 10 seconds here just for testing. Also, I'm not sure why window.setTimeout isn't working. Not that I'm an expert in jquery or JS.

Comment: does the timing need to be exact or are you satisfied as long as it's kind of like ten seconds in between?

Comment: Exact precision is not required. I just don't want to hit the service very frequently, hence introducing a small delay. That's all.

Comment: @apratim2002 Any luck?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need think about create a bulk action in the server for replay all info in a single shot.

The other important concept, **avoid the sync connections**. In your case 100 connection will block the browser during the process.

All elements is write in the same moment for use sync, the browser is block for write any element in the dom.

https://jsfiddle.net/luarmr/3a81nn9z/

the first:
Remember that the browser has a call limitations, it is true that the user can change it in this configuration, maybe it is not your solution, but introduce concept to the second and third solution, in this case we ask for all request in the same moment.

HTML

```
<ul id="result"></ul>
```

JS

```
function insertPosition(pos, text){
    var element = $("#result > li:nth-child(" + (pos+1) + ")"),
        html = '<li>' + text + '</li>';
    if (element.length === 0) {
         $("#result").append(html);
    } else {
       element.before(html);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < numberRequest; i++) {        
        $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/html/', 
            type: 'POST',      
            data: 'html=' + i,     
            cache: false,
            success: insertPosition.bind(this, i)
        });    
    }
});
```

Basically, you call the ajax inside the loop, and you need be sure to add the new element in the correct place. insertPosition test if you already have an element in that position, if you have one the function insert the element before it. If you don't have, they insert the element in the last position.
The other important here is the function bind, [you can see more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).
No wait, when I have the element I add it in the list.

The second (same html):

```
var callbackFunction = function(num, max, returnhtml){
    num++;
    $("#result2").append('<li>' + returnhtml + '</li>');
    if (num<max) {
        callAjax(num,max);    
    }
};

function callAjax(num,max){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/html/', 
        type: 'POST',      
        data: 'html=' + num,     
        cache: false,
        success: callbackFunction.bind(this, num, max)
    });  
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    callAjax(0,numberRequest);
});
```

The difference here is the number of concurrent connections. In this case, we wait for the response and then we send the next request. We can always insert in the end.

Third way:

```
var callbackFunction2 = function (num, max, returnhtml) {
    num++;
    $("#result3").append('<li>' + returnhtml + '</li>');
    if (num < max) {
        setTimeout(window.callAjax2.bind(window, num, max), 500);
    }
};

function callAjax2(num, max) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/html/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'html=' + num,
        cache: false,
        success: callbackFunction2.bind(this, num, max)
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    callAjax2(0, numberRequest);
});
```

This is only an update of second version, with a timeout.
Actually I prefer the second one for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the loop variable as a multiplier for your time to achieve that:

```
  for (var i=0;i<100;i++) {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url:
        datatype: 'json'
        async: false
        success: function to display row
      });
    }, i * 200);
  }
```

Comment: That does seem to work. Thanks, but it would help if you could give some short explanation. It is in a loop. I have a setTimeout. Then why doesn't it wait after every call? Does the ajax call happen in a different thread of execution?

Comment: Every setTimeout call is asynchronous,  that is why it it runs only after every other call is done. Loop just sets the time to run and the code inside is running 200ms later. The second timeout runs 400ms later, etc

Comment: Be careful, If a request is longest than 200 milliseconds this code doesn´t work as expected and you have a random error.

Comment: @RaúlMartín could you give a proof?

Comment: it is a random error, execute several times and look that the number are not always in the right order.

Comment: it is not "an error", they must not be in the same order. This is happening because of asynchronous requests. If you want to make them in the same order just make the request synchronous (check jQuery docs how to make synchronous ajax calls) and they will be loaded one after another and will be waiting for each other. I'm not going to explain it here because there are lots of answers on this topic already. The code in the answer calls the server once a 200ms - that was requested and it at least attempts to do that.

Comment: Don't have the control about the order of the row usually is a problem. You have a solution in the next reply. It is not complicated. As well use sync connection is a bad idea. Because you block all js, if you launch 100 connections the user can't use the page for a while.

Comment: I know that, but this is an answer for a concrete question with concrete requirements where the synchronous call is done in author's code. The discussion is obsolete.